# Handlebars and Ember bundles

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, textmatebundles

Are there any Textmate 2.0 bundles that are available for Handlebars, Ember, or both?

I did find the following:

https://github.com/drnic/Handlebars.tmbundle

but it hasn't been updated in 2 years and I couldn't really get to work for me effectively in Textmate 2 (although it's possible my way of hacking it in was the problem).

Comment: For anyone interested in how I hacked the above bundle into TM2 ... I created my own bundle called Handlebars and then double clicked the dictionary and all snippets (in every case associating them to my new handlebars bundle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to add handlebars to Textmate2 you need to clone the git to

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles
```

[source](http://skipjack.info/?p=1098)

Comment: Hm, just came across this when trying to install a bundle. According to the docs the bundle location should be `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles` for Textmate 2. http://blog.macromates.com/2013/2-0-status-and-faq/